# How to get longtext to default to empty string

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

I am using mysql 5.1.36 and SQLyog.

I have a longtext field in my table. However, it defaults to 'null' meaning that when I get the data it actually returns the word 'null'.

How can I alter the table to instead of defaulting to null, it is just empty?

Comment: Your query is not clear. Do you want to convey that 1. on an empty table, SQLYog should display no rows while on `Grid View`? 2. `NULL` entry in column shall be displayed as `''` (empty) string?

Comment: When I do a query from PHP, I would like to receive an empty string if nothing has been added to the longtext field. If I edit it in SQLyog, it is an empty string. However, my calls from PHP are getting the word 'null'. SQLYog does not allow you to specify an empty string as its starting contents.